# How To Add Plugin To The VideoJs The Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, html5-video, vimeo

I'am new in wordpress plugins development 
and I want to learn how can add some techniques to the popular wordpress plugin "[Video.js - HTML5 Video Player for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/)" 
 
in this case I want to add the "[videojs-vimeo](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-vimeo)" plugin to the VideoJs plugin 
Can I go to my wordpress plugins page and add the links to the new videoJs-vimeo plugin , and that's it ?

Many Thanks .

Comment: If [videojs-vimeo](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-vimeo) is compatible with wordpress plugin [Video.js - HTML5 Video Player for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) then you just need to add Videojs-vimeo and that's it. Also want to tell you that the worpdress plugin you are using is not compatible with latest version of the wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the question is where to put Videojs-vimeo ?

Comment: You can simply enqueue in your `functions.php`. So it will be run in every page.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to learn the basic concept of how to develop wordpress plugin.Check some tut here or you can check videos in youtube

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin
http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin

When you familiar with how to create wordpress plugin you got the concept how to edit the plugin

Comment: I watch a lot of tuts , but I still don't know what to do to edit this plugin , but i will try again , thanks .

Comment: I am also finding the way to use some plugins of Video.JS in "Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator" wordpress plugin. Did you find any solution?